# Change color in listview item and remove item UWP

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp

I would remove an item with button inside listview item and change color of ellipse with another button in listview item.

The class product code:

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

The xaml mainpage code:

```
<Page
x:Class="ListViewTest.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ListViewTest"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewProducts" 
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            FontSize="18" 
            BorderThickness="0" 
            Width="600" 
            Height="800" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            ItemsSource="{Binding LineItems}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                        <Ellipse x:Name="EllipseColor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnRemove" Click="btnRemove_Click" Height="20" Width="60" Margin="5"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnChangeColor" Click="btnChangeColor_Click" Height="20" Width="60" Margin="5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The code behind of mainpage:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Product> _listProduct = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        _listProduct = new ObservableCollection<Product>
        {
            new Product
            {
                Name = "Phone",
                Price = 100
            },
            new Product
            {
                Name = "TV",
                Price = 120
            },
            new Product
            {
                Name = "Computer",
                Price = 80
            },
            new Product
            {
                Name = "Laptop",
                Price = 250
            },
            new Product
            {
                Name = "Tablet",
                Price = 150
            },
            new Product
            {
                Name = "Monitor",
                Price = 200
            },
        };
        ListViewProducts.ItemsSource = _listProduct;
    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Code to remove item
    }

    private void btnChangeColor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Code to color EllipseColor
    }
}
```

With btnRemove i would delete listview item and with btnChangeColor i would color red the fill of EllipseColor, in btnChangeColor_Click i would the index of item.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me like you've got several issues. First off is that you're setting your `ListView` source via binding to an apparently non-existent collection, as well as setting it in C#. You should move it to using a proper binding. For example, in `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
private ObservableCollection<Product> _products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get => _products; set => _products = value; }
```

And then bind to it:

```
<ListView ItemsSource={x:Bind Products, Mode=OneWay} />
```

Then, in `btnRemove_Click`, you can just remove the item from the collection:

```
var product = (sender as Button).DataContext as Product;
Products.Remove(product);
```

As for coloring the `Ellipse`, you shouldn't really do that in C#. Instead, you should have a `Status` property on your `Product` class, and then change that property.

First off, you'll need to make sure your property changes fire notifications.

```
public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _status;
    public string Status
    {
        get => _status;
        set
        {
            _status = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Status)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Then change the property.

```
var product = (sender as Button).DataContext as Product;
product.Status = "invalid";
```

Then in your XAML, use a binding converter to change the `Ellipse`'s `Fill` property based on the status. E.g.

```
using System;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

public class StatusConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) =>
        new SolidColorBrush(value.ToString() == "invalid" ? Colors.Red : Colors.Gray);

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => 
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

You'll then need to add the converter to your resources.

```
<Page...>
    <Page.Resources>
        <locationofyourconverter:StatusConverter x:Key="StatusConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>

    ...

    <Ellipse Fill={Binding Status, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter}} />
```

Comment: Sorry but I can not understand the two solutions.
Could you explain better remove item troght MyCollection?
How do I use MyCollection?

Comment: @Res I've updated the answer to show the collection (renamed to `Products`.) If you need help beyond that I'd suggest you take a look at [XAML Binding Basics 101](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2012/10/12/xaml-binding-basics-101/) by Jerry Nixon.

Comment: The elimination of the item works!! But I did not manage to use ivalueconverter. just this pleasee ..

Comment: @Res. Alright. I've updated the answer to show the full use of the converter. But that's really all the more I can do within the context of an answer.

Comment: Ivalueconverter works when the application starts, but if I press the button the color does not change .. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Res It just struck me what the problem is. See my updated answer.

Comment: Now when start the fill is nothing and the button don't work